# CSS Hover Underline Animation

Tags: html, css, animation, hover, onhover

I'm trying to create a line animation when I hover over a piece of text. Here's the code I have right now, but it's not working.

```
[data-predefined-style="true"] small {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-family: "Diatype Variable", Icons;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
    font-variation-settings: 'slnt' 0, 'MONO' 0;
}

[data-predefined-style="true"] small a {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
    border-bottom-width: 0em;
}

[data-predefined-style="true"] small a:hover {
    color: rgba(0, 46, 207, 0.8);
    border-bottom-width: 0em;
}

.hover-underline-animation {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: #0087ca;
}

.hover-underline-animation:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #0087ca;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
}

.hover-underline-animation:hover:after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

I have the code for the hover animation, but I'm not exactly sure how to implement it. Help is greatly appreciated, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working. What kind of effect are you after?

```css
[data-predefined-style="true"] small {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-family: "Diatype Variable", Icons;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
}

[data-predefined-style="true"] small a {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  border-bottom-width: 0em;
}

[data-predefined-style="true"] small a:hover {
  color: rgba(0, 46, 207, 0.8);
  border-bottom-width: 0em;
}

.hover-underline-animation {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: #0087ca;
}

.hover-underline-animation:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #0087ca;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
}

.hover-underline-animation:hover:after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover-underline-animation">Hello world</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this can help you

```css
[data-predefined-style="true"] small {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-family: "Diatype Variable", Icons;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
    font-variation-settings: 'slnt' 0, 'MONO' 0;
}

[data-predefined-style="true"] small a {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
    border-bottom-width: 0em;
}

[data-predefined-style="true"] small a:hover {
    color: rgba(0, 46, 207, 0.8);
    border-bottom-width: 0em;
}

.hover-underline-animation {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: #0087ca;
}

.hover-underline-animation:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #0087ca;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
}

.hover-underline-animation:hover:after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="hover-underline-animation">text with underline animation</h2>
```